# find inorder successor in BST without using any extra space

Tags: algorithm

I am looking a way to find out inorder successor of a node in BST withut using extra space.

Comment: What information is stored at each node? And what part are you finding difficult? The definition of "inorder"? Finding the successor? Or is it that you have a method, but your method uses extra space?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764799/applying-a-logarithm-to-navigate-a-tree

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the inorder successor of a given node `N` we use the following rules:

- If `N` has a right child `R` then the
  `inorderSuccessor(N)` is the leftmost
  decedent of `R`.
- Else `inorderSuccessor(N)` is the closest
  ancestor, `M`, of `N` (if it exists)
  such that `N` is descended from the
  left child of `M`. If there is no such ancestor, inorderSucessor does not exist.

Consider a sample tree:

```
     A
    / \
   B   C
  / \ 
 D   E
    /
   F
```

Whose inorder traversal gives: `D B F E A C`

`inorderSuccessor(A)` = `C` as `C` is the leftmost decedent of the right child of `A`.

`inorderSuccessor(B)` = `F` as `F` is the leftmost decedent of the right child of `B`.

`inorderSuccessor(C)` = Does not exist.

`inorderSuccessor(D)` = `B` as `B` is the left child of `D`.

`inorderSuccessor(E)` = `A`. `E` does not have a right child so we have scenario 2. We go to parent of `E` which is `B`, but `E` is right decedent of `B`, so we move to parent of `B` which is `A` and `B` is left decedent of `A` so `A` is the answer.

`inorderSuccessor(F)` = `E` as `F` is the left child of `E`.

Procedure:

```
treeNodePtr inorderSucessor(treeNodePtr N) {
        if(N) {
                treeNodePtr tmp;
                // CASE 1: right child of N exists.
                if(N->right) {
                        tmp = N->right;
                        // find leftmost node.
                        while(tmp->left) {
                                tmp = tmp->left;
                        }
                // CASE 2: No right child.
                } else {
                        // keep climbing till you find a parent such that
                        // node is the left decedent of it.
                        while((tmp = N->parent)) {
                                if(tmp->left == N) {
                                        break;
                                }
                                N = tmp;
                        }
                }
                return tmp;
        }
        // No IOS.
        return NULL;
}
```

[**Code In Action**](http://www.ideone.com/imqy2)

Comment: Small correction in your explanation of inorderSuccessor(D): it is D who is the left child of B.

Answer (score 5):

The following method helps you determine the inorder successor **WITHOUT ANY PARENT NODE OR EXTRA SPACE NON-RECURSIVELY**

```
struct node * inOrderSuccessor(struct node *root, struct node *n)
   { 
   //*If the node has a right child, return the smallest value of the right sub tree*

   if( n->right != NULL ) 
      return minValue(n->right); 

   //*Return the first ancestor in whose left subtree, node n lies*
   struct node *succ=NULL;
   while(root) 
   { 
      if(n->datadata < root->data) 
         {
            succ=root; root=root->left; 
         }

      else if(n->data > root->data) 
         root=root->right; 
      else break; 
   } 
  return succ;
 }
```

I'm quite certain this is right. Do correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If the given node has a right child - go to it, and then follow iteratively the left children until you reach a node N with no left children. Return N.

Otherwise, follow the parents until you first find a parent where the node is a left child. Return this parent.

```
Node InOrderSuccessor(Node node) {
    if (node.right() != null) {
        node = node.right()
        while (node.left() != null) 
            node = node.left()
        return node
    } else {
        parent = node.getParent();
        while (parent != null && parent.right() == node) {
            node = parent
            parent = node.getParent()
        }
        return parent
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. What if the given node has no right child and is its parent's right child? You will return a smaller node then.

Comment: node.getparent() works only if the Node class stores the parent of each node!

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the root of a node, then it's just a matter of moving pointers around, so no extra space. See [this lecture](http://faculty.salisbury.edu/~ealu/COSC320/Lectures/succ_pred_rules.pdf).