# Applying a Logarithm to Navigate a Tree

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, tree, traversal

I had once known of a way to use logarithms to move from one leaf of a tree to the next "in-order" leaf of a tree.  I think it involved taking a position value (rank?) of the "current" leaf and using it as a seed for a fresh traversal from the root down to the new target leaf - all the way using a log function test to determine whether to follow the right or left node down to the leaf.

I no longer recall how to exercise that technique.  Can anyone re-introduce me?

I also don't recall if the technique required the tree to be balanced, or if it worked on n-trees or only binary trees.  Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like it might apply to trees stored as arrays.

Comment: @Steven: The technique had no bearing on how it was stored in memory. When I originally learned this, it was simply a textbook geometric-pictorial exercise. The primary significance was how the logarithm was applied.

Comment: Are you sure it was a tree? There is an algorithm called spiral hashing that uses logarithm to choose a hash bucket.

Comment: @erickson: most definately it was applied to a tree.  I stil recall my procedural solution to the same problem.  But the mathematical approach was much more helpful.

Comment: @Myst: I'm sure you are mistaken, since what you describe implies random access. List-based structures don't offer random access; arrays do.

Comment: @Steven What does 'random access' mean in this context? If I assign each node in my list an attribute called 'position' have I turned my 'list' into an 'array'? If I assign each node in a graph this same attribute, and then use this attribute to access nodes, does this stop being a graph? I believe this is an important semantic issue, but it is my view that the underlying implementation and API provided is what makes the datastructure what it is. If Cormen, Leiserson and Rivest read StackOverflow, we could ask them...

Comment: @Brian: This isn't complicated. If I'm traversing a tree encoded as a packed array, I can walk the nodes in any order at all. With a linked list implementation (one link for left child, a second for right child, possibly others for parent or other traversals), I can only follow the links; I cannot directly go to a node. Therefore, knowing the number of the node doesn't help me any.

Comment: @Steven Yes, I understand that you must still follow the links, as that is the only thing to follow for this implementation. Doesn't this technique 'help' you by always following the correct link? If you have links for left, right, parent and child, this will give you a sequence of down-down-down-right-right-rights to take, won't it? Maybe I am missing something. I'm not sure about 'optimal' though.

Comment: @Brian: No, I don't think it'll help at all. If there's a case I'm missing, I'd be curious to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the answer, or at least a facsimile.

Assume the tree nodes are numbered, starting at 1, top-down and left-to-right.  Assume traversal begins at the root, and halts when it finds node X (which means the parent is linked to its children).  Also, for quick reference, the base 2 logarithmic values for nodes 1 through 12 are:

```
log2(1) = 0.0
log2(2) = 1
log2(3) = 1.58
log2(4) = 2
log2(5) = 2.32     
log2(6) = 2.58     
log2(7) = 2.807
log2(8) = 3
log2(9) = 3.16
log2(10) = 3.32
log2(11) = 3.459
log2(12) = 3.58
```

The fractional portion represents a unique diagonal position (notice how nodes 3, 6, and 12 all have fractional portion 0.58).  Also notice that every node belongs either to the left or right side of the tree, depending on whether the log fractional component is less or great than 0.5.  Anecdotes aside, the algorithm for finding a node is then as follows:

- examine fractional portion, if it is less than .5, turn left.  Else turn right.
- subtract one from the whole number portion of the log, stop if the value reaches zero.
- double the fractional portion, and start over.

So, for example, if node 11 is what you seek then you start by computing the log which is 3.459.  Then...

1. 3-459   <=fraction less than .5: turn left and decrement whole number to 2.
2. 2-918   <=doubled fraction more than .5: turn right and decrement whole number to 1.
3. 1-836   <=doubling .918 gives 1.836: but only fractional part counts: turn right and dec prior whole number to 0.  Done!!

With appropriate accomodations, the same technique appears to work for any balanced n-ary tree.  For example, given a balanced ternary tree, the choice of following left, middle, or right edges is again based on the fractional portion of the log, as follows:

```
between 0.5-0.832: turn left  (a one-third fraction range)
between 0.17-0.49: turn right  (another one-third fraction range)
otherwise go down the middle.  (the last one-third range)
```

The algorithm is adjusted by multiplying the fractional portion by 3 instead of 2.  Again, a quick reference for those who want to test this last statement:

```
log3(1) = 0.0
log3(2) = 0.63          
log3(3) = 1             
log3(4) = 1.26          
log3(5) = 1.46
log3(6) = 1.63
log3(7) = 1.77
log3(8) = 1.89          
log3(9) = 2
```

At this point I wonder if there is an even more concise way to express this whole "log-based top-down selection of a node."  I'm interested if anyone knows...

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned whether to go left or right, I'm going to assume you're talking about a binary tree specifically.  In that case, I think you're right that there is a way.  If your nodes are numbered left-to-right, top-to-bottom, starting with 1, then you can find the rank (depth in the tree) by taking the log2 of the node's number.  To find that node again from the root, you can use the binary representation of the number, where 0 = left and 1 = right.

For example:

- n = 11
- 11 in binary is 1011
- We always ignore the first 1 since it's going to be there for every number (all nodes of rank n will be binary numbers with n+1 digits, with the first digit being 1).  We're left with 011,  which is saying from the root go left, then right, then right.

If you want to find the next in-order leaf, take the current leaf's number and add one, then traverse from the root using this method.

I believe this only works with balanced binary trees.

Comment: Of course, from a coding perspective just have nodes store a pointer to their parent. But it's a good academic problem.

Comment: No, this technique will work on a tree of any order, as long as it is filled out completely at each level, and as you described left to right and top to bottom (a "full tree", "complete tree"?). You take log base n of your node's number and that is how many levels down you are. I don't think the left-to-right makes a difference, as long as you are consistent with how you index in. Then, you can subtract (node's #) - (n ^ number you received) to get how far you are to the left. Your example used base 2 for a binary tree, but there is no reason this concept cannot be generalized for any base.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this proposal requires more characters than I can fit into a comment box. Steven does not believe that knowing the depth of the node in the tree is useful. I think it is. I have been wrong in the past, and I'm sure I'll be wrong in the future, so I will try to explain how this idea works in an attempt to not be wrong in the present. If I am, I apologize ahead of time. I'm nearly certain I got it from one of my Algorithms and Datastructures courses, using the CLR book. Please excuse any slips in notation or nomenclature, I haven't studied this stuff in a while.

Quoting [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), "*a complete binary tree is a binary tree in which every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes are as far left as possible.*"

We are considering a complete tree with any branching degree (where a binary tree has a branching degree of two). Also, we are considering our nodes to have a 'positional value' which is an ordering of the positional value (top to bottom, left to right) of the node.

Now, if we are given a positional value, we can find the node in the following fashion. Take the log_base_n of the positional value of the element we are looking for (floor of this, we want an integer). Traverse down from the root that many times, minus one. Now, start looking through all the children of the nodes at this level. Your node you are searching for will be in this set.

This is an attempt in explaining the additional part of the wikipedia definition:

```
"This depth is equal to the integer part of log2(n) where n 
 is the number of nodes on  the balanced tree. 

 Example 1: balanced tree with 1 node, log2(1) = 0 (depth = 0). 

 Example 2: balanced tree with 3 nodes, log2(3) = 1.59 (depth=1). 

 Example 3: balanced tree with 5 nodes, log2(5) = 2.32 
 (depth of tree is 2 nodes)."
```

This is useful, because you can simply traverse down to this level and then start looking around. It is useful and important to know the depth your node is located on, so you can start looking there, instead of starting to look at the beginning. Unless you know what level of the tree you are on, you get to start looking at all the nodes sequentially.

That is why I think it is helpful to know the depth of the node we are searching for.

It is a little bit odd, since having the "positional value" is not something we normally care about in a tree. I can see why Steve thought of this in terms of an array, since positional value is inherent in arrays.

-Brian J. Stinar-

Answer (score 1):

Something that at least resembles your description is the [Binary Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), used a.o. in Priority Queues.

Comment: Yes, the part that matches is the idea of implementing a binary tree in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: Nodes **have** pointers to their parent

Starting from the `node`, traverse up the `parent` pointer until one with non-null `right_child` is found. Go to the `right_child` and traverse `left_child` as long as they are non-null.

Case 2: Nodes **do not have** pointers to the parent

Starting from the `root`, find the path to the `node` (including the `root` and the `node`). Then find the latest vertex (i.e. a node) in the path that has non-null `right_child`. Go the the `right_child` and traverse `left_child` as long as they are non-null.

In both cases, we traversing either up or down from the root to one of the nodes. The maximum of such traversal is in the order of the depth of the tree, hence logarithmic in the size of the nodes if the tree is balanced.